# Type hint for key value pair list?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm fairly new to python and creating types using python. Still wrapping my head around it.

I'm trying to come up with a way of defining a key value pair list using typings.

the structure I'm talking about is:

```
[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2','value2'},...]
```

The best I could come up with is:

```
List[Dict[str,str]]
```

But I'm sure this is wrong.

Comment: Seems correct to me

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: Why not just use a single, flat dict?  What purpose does the list serve, other than to force a search instead of a direct lookup?

Comment: i kind of don't really know what that means @TomKarzes.  I'm a bit of a python newbie. I'm creating object types using TypedDict classes.  I'm coming from using Typescript a lot and used to defining my type structures,  so maybe I'm taking the wrong approach. 

Out of interest, how would I get the keys from this?  eg if i used list(my_list.keys()) it's throwing an error. (my_list being of List[Dict[str,str]] type)

Comment: What you have is a list of *dictionaries* {with string keys and values}.

Comment: The normal way to do this is with a single dict:  `{'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2', ...}`  That way you can access `d['key1']` to either retrieve `'value1'` or change it.  That's the point of a dictionary.  Putting it in a list would defeat the purpose.